# Integrating SpringHttpInvoker with WSO2 ESB?

Tags: spring, esb, wso2, spring-remoting, wso2-esb

I have multiple Spring HttpInvoker services, and want to integrate them with WSO2 ESB. I am really new to ESB workd, so anyone can help me?

```
S1: http://10.0.1.75:8080/integration/ws/switch
S2: http://10.0.1.75:8080/beachon/ws/controller
S3: http://10.0.1.75:8080/ola/ws/mixture
```

I want to integrate all these into WSO2 ESB and having a single calling interface from WSO2 ESB.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by a feature called service chaining. Please have a look at these[1][2].

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining
[2] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/04/integrate-rules-soa